# $f(1)=a$ and homomorphism in $(\mathbb{Z},.)$? How so?

Tags: group-theory

> **Exercise**: Let $G$ be a finite group, find the number of homomorphisms: i)$f:\mathbb{Z}\to G$. ii) $f:G\to\mathbb{Z}$
>
> **Solution**: i) As $\mathbb{Z}=\langle 1\rangle$ is an infinite cyclic group, then for each $a\in G$ there is only one homomorphism  $f:\mathbb{Z}\to G$ such that $f(1)=a$, therefore there are as many homeomorphisms as the number of elements in $G$
> ii) As $G$ has finite order then any element  $a\in G$ must have a finite order and since $f:G\to\mathbb{Z}$ is a homomorphism, $f(a)$ has finite order, therefore there is an unique trivial homomorphism $f:G\to\mathbb{Z}$, so that $f(a)=0$.

I think the author´s solution is wrong because the homomorphism should be f(0)=a, once if it was f(1)=a, the order of $1$ would be infinite. According to ii), the author must be referring to the group $\mathbb{Z},+$ as in i), the author may be referring to $(\mathbb{Z}-{0},.)$ however as it is stated $\mathbb{Z}$ we must assume the operation is the sum.

**Question:**

Is my line of thinking right? Is the solution wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The solution is correct, except that in the first part, they should say "there is one and only one" instead of "there is only one"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen How can $f(1)=a$ be a homomorphism if the order of $a$ is finite and the order of $1$ is infinite?

Comment: Pedro: Think of the mapping $f(n)=\overline{n}$ from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Z}_m$ for some integer $m>0$. It is a homomorphism, right?
After all $$\overline{a+b}=\overline{a}+\overline{b}$$ by the usual residue class arithmetic.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen             I am sorry but I am not understanding how this can be an homomorphism since the order of $n$ would be infinite and $\overline{n}$ would be finite. Is it not a condition for an homomorphism to exist that the when the order is infinite so it is the image order?

Comment: No. It is the other way round. If $a^n=1_G$ then for a homomorphism  $f:G\to G'$ then  we  also have 
$$f(a)^n=f(a^n)=f(1_G)=1_{G'}.$$ But if $f(a)^n=1_{G'}$ then we cannot "pull back" that piece of information to say anything about $a^n$. Also. If $f(x)=\overline{x}$, then for all $x,y$
$$f(x)+f(y)=\overline{x}+\overline{y}=\overline{x+y}=f(x+y),$$ so $f$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen               I finally got it. I misunderstood a theorem. You answered my question. Thank you very much!